# Grab min value in PHP from MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, min

So I have some numbers that take the name "id" in my MySQL database. I tried this code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))     
{
$id=$row['id'];
$user = $row['usrname'];
$fname = $row['fname'];
$lname = $row['lname'];
echo "<strong>User:</strong> ".$user." ".$fname." ".$lname."<br/>";
echo min($id);
}
```

On the last line I tried to echo the min value for id, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

ANSWER: Use "ASC LIMIT 1"

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){    
$id=$row['id'];     
$user = $row['usrname'];     
$fname = $row['fname'];     
$lname = $row['lname'];
echo "<strong>User:</strong> ".$user." ".$fname." ".$lname."<br/>";     
echo $id; 
}
```

Comment: Please also show your query; do you want just the fields associated with the minimum `id`?

Comment: Thank you all! I love you frickin geniuses!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))     
{
    $id=$row['id'];
    $user = $row['usrname'];
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];

    echo "<strong>User:</strong> ".$user." ".$fname." ".$lname."<br/>";
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: @Ken: `ASC` means "sort in ascending order", and `LIMIT 1` means "select at most 1 row."

Comment: Thanks! Now from here I can do whatever I want with this row! You guys rock :D +1

Comment: @Ken if you want max number (last user in table) just replace ASC with DESC. @Matt Ball, thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Ken if you want 10 first users then it is `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10`, if you 10 last users then `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`, if you want only one, check @dar7yl solution. No problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT min(id) as min FROM users';
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$min_id = $row['min'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot change the query order (sort by names?), you can determine the lowest $id by using a helper variable:

```
 $min = isset($min) ? min($min, $id) : $id;
```

And then `print $min;` after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If not able to use `MIN()` in MySQL, try this...

```
$smallestId = -PHP_INT_MAX;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   ...
   $smallestId = min($smallestId, $id);
}
```

If you never have any negative ids (you shouldn't), you could just change `-PHP_INT_MAX` to `0`.